# SQLite query matching only on multiple rows or the same ID

Tags: sql, select, sqlite

I have a system which tags files with text labels. Each file has several tags. The relevant tables/columns are:

```
taggings(fileHash,tagId)
tags(tagId,tagText)
```

How do I find all tagId which have both a row where tagText matches query 1 and another row where it matches query 2? In other words, how can I find each fileHash that has both of two tags when the tags are in separate rows as shown above?

Is there a way to do this for an arbitrary number of matches?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24326641/sqlite-joining-rows-in-the-same-table) which seems related, but when I try to write a query like that, I get an "Unable to prepare statement" error.

### Sample Data

#### Taggings

```
fileHash    tagId
404ba9      1
404ba9      2
e04f90      1
e04f90      3
```

#### Tags

```
tagId       tagText
1           document
2           personal
3           work
```

### Expected Result

If a user searched for both `personal` and `document` as defined in `tags`, return `404ba9` because both (404ba9, 1) and (404ba9,2) exist in `taggings`.

Comment: Sample data and expected results, please. A few rows will go a long way.

Comment: My question was answered, but I added sample data and expected results for anybody who comes across this post in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd join the tables, have a condition on the tags, and count the number of matches:

```
SELECT   fileHash
FROM     taggings 
JOIN     tags ON taggings.tagId = tags.tagId
WHERE    tagText IN ('text1', 'text2')
GROUP BY fileHash
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: Thanks this worked great. I use SQL just rarely enough that I somehow didn't have to use HAVING until now.